# what does the dtype=None in pandas.read_csv do?

Tags: python, pandas

So, the default argument to pandas.read_csv, dtype is None. What does this do and how would it be different from dtype=str?

Does it infer the column types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dtype=None` means that pandas will attempt to *infer* the data type from your column values. This can become **extremely slow** for larger frames, so if you're certain all your data is string, or that you don't want it converted to the appropriate dtype just yet, specify `dtype=object`.

From the [documentation for `read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> `dtype` : Type name or dict of column -> type, default `None`
>   Data type for data or columns. E.g. `{'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32}` **Use `str` or
>   `object` to preserve and not interpret `dtype`.**

Answer (score 0):

When `dtype=None`, pandas automatically infers the data types of columns based on the content. For example, if a column contains only numbers, pandas might interpret it as an integer or float type.

On the other hand, `dtype=str` explicitly tells pandas to treat all columns as strings, regardless of their content.